# Swift: inner Data-typed variable was encoded via JSONEncoder. How to deserialize it properly?

Tags: json, swift, nsdata, codable, jsonencoder

Consider the next example:

```
import Foundation 

class UDFrame: Codable {

    var data:Data

    init(data:Data) {
        self.data = data
    }

}


class Event: Codable {

    var name:String

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }

}

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let event = Event(name: "eventName")
let serializedEvent = try encoder.encode(event)
let frame = UDFrame(data: serializedEvent)
let serializedFrame = try encoder.encode(frame)
print(String(data: serializedFrame, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
```

Result of the `print` statement is next: `{"data":"eyJuYW1lIjoiZXZlbnROYW1lIn0="}`.

My question is how to get `"eventName"` out of this drivel?

And, if possible, could you please explain why `Data` is serialized in such way by `JSONEncoder`, and what's the way to get initial data on another platform when such a JSON is given?

Comment: Seems to be Base64Encoding to me, to make the "data" readable/safe converted into a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `JSONDecoder` for decoding a JSON-encoded `Data`.

`Data` is simply `base64encoded`, so you just need to base64 decode it on another platform to get back the original data. However, there's no need to store a JSON-encoded object as a property of another object, you can simply use the JSON-encoded object.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know it is in base64